# Subtracting Two Columns of DataFrames not giving expected result - Python, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subtraction

I have two data frames, each with 672 rows of data.

I want to subtract the values in a column of one data frame from the values in a column of the other data frame. The result can either be a new data frame, or a series, it does not really matter to me. The size of the result should obviously be 672 rows or 672 values.

I have the code:

```
stock_returns = beta_portfolios_196307_201906.iloc[:,6] - \
    fama_french_factors_196307_201906.iloc[:,4]
```

I also tried

```
stock_returns = beta_portfolios_196307_201906["Lo 10"] + \
    fama_french_factors_196307_201906["RF"]
```

For both, the result is a series size (1116, ), and most of the value in the series are `NaN`, with a few being numeric values.

Could someone please explain why this happening and how I can get the result I want?

Here is a the .head() of my data frames:

```
beta_portfolios_196307_201906.head()
     Date  Lo 20  Qnt 2  Qnt 3  Qnt 4  ...  Dec 6  Dec 7  Dec 8  Dec 9  Hi 10
0  196307   1.13  -0.08  -0.97  -0.94  ...  -1.20  -0.49  -1.39  -1.94  -0.77
1  196308   3.66   4.77   6.46   6.23  ...   7.55   7.57   4.91   9.04  10.47
2  196309  -2.78  -0.76  -0.78  -0.81  ...  -0.27  -0.63  -1.00  -1.92  -3.68
3  196310   0.74   3.56   2.03   5.70  ...   1.78   6.63   4.78   3.10   3.01
4  196311  -0.63  -0.26  -0.81  -0.92  ...  -0.69  -1.32  -0.51  -0.20   0.52

[5 rows x 16 columns]
```

```
fama_french_factors_196307_201906.head()

       Date  Mkt-RF   SMB   HML    RF
444  196307   -0.39 -0.56 -0.83  0.27
445  196308    5.07 -0.94  1.67  0.25
446  196309   -1.57 -0.30  0.18  0.27
447  196310    2.53 -0.54 -0.10  0.29
448  196311   -0.85 -1.13  1.71  0.27
```

One last thing I should add: At first, all of the values in both data frames were strings, so I had to convert the values to numeric values using:

```
beta_portfolios_196307_201906 = beta_portfolios_196307_201906.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Please provide examples for your DataFrames.

Comment: I just added some more info about my data frames.

Comment: Try first doing `fama_french_factors_196307_201906.index = list(range(len(beta_portfolios_196307_201906.index))))` then perform the subtraction again. The `fama_french_factors_196307_201906` indices are not the same as the `beta_portfolios_196307_201906` indices.

Comment: @duncster94 that did the trick, thank you! I also tried setting the indices of both Dataframes to equal the column "Dates" with this code:

fama_french_factors_196307_201906 =fama_french_factors_196307_201906.set_index("Date")
beta_portfolios_196307_201906 =beta_portfolios_196307_201906.set_index("Date")

And that worked as well!

Comment: Glad to have helped and good call. In the future you can specify the `"Date"` column to be your index when you import the DataFrame - it'll save you the step of having to change the index.

Answer (score 0):

Let's explain the issue on an example with just 5 rows.

When both DataFrames, *a* and *b* have the same indices, e.g.:

```
a                    b

   Lo 10  Xxx            RF  Yyy
0     10    1        0   9    1
1     20    1        1   8    1
2     30    1        2   7    1
3     40    1        3   6    1
4     50    1        4   5    1
```

The result of subtraction `a['Lo 10'] - b['RF']` is:

```
0     1
1    12
2    23
3    34
4    45
dtype: int64
```

Rows of both DataFrames are **aligned on the index** and then corresponding
elements are subtracted.

And now take a look at the case when *b* has some **other** indices, e.g.:

```
   RF  Yyy
0   9    1
1   8    1
2   7    1
8   6    1
9   5    1
```

i.e. last 2 rows have index *8* and *9* **absent** in *a*.

Then the result of the same subtraction is:

```
0     1.0
1    12.0
2    23.0
3     NaN
4     NaN
8     NaN
9     NaN
dtype: float64
```

i.e.:

- rows with index *0*, *1* and *2* - as before - both DataFrames have these
  values.
- but if some index is present in **only one** DataFrame, the result is
  *NaN*,
- the number of rows in this result is bigger.

If you want to align both columns **by position** instead of by the index, you
can run `a.reset_index()['Lo 10'] - b.reset_index()['RF']`, getting the
result as in the first case.